# Performance bottleneck for SQL Table-Valued Function for CSVtoTable

Tags: performance, csv, t-sql, azure-sql-database, table-variable

I am working on a query where I need to convert a CSV value holding few ID's sepearated by `,`.

Currently I am using a Table-Values Function taken from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732596/Converting-comma-separated-data-in-a-column-to-row):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
   RETURN
END
GO
```

I use it in my view like this:

```
Select * from SomeTable S where ID in (Select * from CSVtoTable(S.CSVIDs))
```

Now I already know that this is going to cause performance issues when operating on a large number of rows in dataset i.e. > 1000. Because the function stores the parsed data to a `Table variable`, and in case of the same function being called 5 times for every row, will definitely cause issues.

**Question:** Is there any way to modify the code for better performance? Better if the same is being called in the view itself.

**Update** : Adding visual of sample data for reference

[image]

SQL server version I am running is:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8
```

Comment: Parsing data via loops are not efficient.   Not clear why you are calling 5 times for every row.  Perhaps a small sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Comment: There suggestions: 1. Don't store it like that; 2. Try using the new `string_split` function 3. Load into a table (variable, temp) the first time and reuse the table not the function

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, lets assume that every row in the actual table has 5 columns with CSV values. To parse that for every column we'll have to call the function 5 times. And for a table of 1000 rows, the function will be called 5000 times.

Comment: I get that, and I'm comfortable with the math  :)  Just saying the visual of sample data may promote a more efficient approach.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, sorry for misunderstanding :). Updated the question with sample visual.

Comment: Got it.  Very helpful especially seeing NULL   ... what version of SQL Server ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, `string_split` needs SQL compatibility >=130 but my current server is on 120 and I do not have access to set its compatibility to 130. On the 3rd suggestion, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, it is `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8` and I've also updated the question with this detail. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: It makes things easier if you tag the version up front. With regards to the third option, you mention _in case of the same function being called 5 times for every row_. Perhaps you could expand on that. Your sample calling query doesn't do that. If you call the function 5 times over with the same parameter, you might be better off first loading it into a table variable and referring to that.  It might also be beneficial to put some more context around it. Maybe there is a better solution than putting a CSV into a single column.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for the explanation :). As of now the function is being called 5 times for every row which I know is very inefficient. The SQL Query does concatenation of the returned data as `XML` which would complicate the question and will be redundant anyhow to the context. Thats the reason I added a sample query i.e. a part of it. :)

Comment: I think you're just going to have to test loading the function result into a table (temp or variable) first, then refer to that table rather than the function. It might be cached anyway and make no difference. Or, depending on the query, perhaps a CTE would reduce code redundancy

Comment: Your `CSVToTable` function is probably one of the worst performing string splitters there is in SQL. You should replace it with a better one. I suggest using Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). This is one of the fastest string splitting functions exists, probably the fastest one that doesn't involve SQLCLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where you concatenate the 5 columns and call a more efficient parser once.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([N_ID] varchar(50),[CSVIDs] varchar(50),[Bar] varchar(50),[Lorem] varchar(50),[Ipsum] varchar(50))

Insert Into @YourTable 
Values (264, '2,3,4', '1,2,3', '1,2,6', '1,2,3'),
       (265, NULL, NULL, '1,2', NULL)

Select A.* 
From @YourTable A
Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-8K] (concat(CSVIDs,',',Bar,',',Lorem,',',ipsum),',') B
Where RetVal = 6
```

**Returns**

```
N_ID    CSVIDs  Bar     Lorem   Ipsum
--------------------------------------
264     2,3,4   1,2,3   1,2,6   1,2,3
```

The UDF if Interested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-8K] 
    (@String VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter VARCHAR(25))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (  
        WITH cte1(N) AS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) N(N)
        ),
        cte2(N) AS
        (
             SELECT TOP (IsNull(DataLength(@String), 0)) 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
             FROM
                 (SELECT N = 1 
                  FROM cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d) A 
        ),
        cte3(N) AS 
        (
             SELECT 1 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT t.N + DataLength(@Delimiter) 
             FROM cte2 t 
             WHERE Substring(@String, t.N, DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
        ),
        cte4(N,L) AS 
        (
             SELECT S.N, ISNULL(NULLIF(CharIndex(@Delimiter, @String, s.N), 0) -S.N, 8000) 
             FROM cte3 S
        )
        SELECT
            RetSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.N),
            RetVal = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, A.N, A.L)))
        FROM
            cte4 A
    );
    -- Original Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```